# Eliminate repetition in updating strings selected randomly within a state property

Tags: swift, swiftui

First, I'm very new to Swift, and coding in general. I'm trying to use the correct terminology, so I apologize if it makes no sense. Doing my best!

Ok, so there appears to be a lot of information/answers on ways to random select strings (or integers, etc) from an array without repetition. However, in my current application, I am not using an array (I kind of am but not directly related to the question). But rather a `@State` designation, in which the variable has an initial value (a string with a number and letter) and is later updated when a button is pushed. The string changes to a randomly selected string from my assets folder based on the file name, which will be the same word but with a different number and letter. What is the simplest way to keep from updating to strings that have already appeared?

Example of what the code looks like:

```
@State var relevantWord = "bird"

Button {
    
    let randoNum = Int.random(in: 1...5)
    
    let x = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
    
    let randoLet = x.randomElement()
    
    relevantWord = "bird" + String(randoNum) + String(randoLet)
}
```

So, the `relevantWord` variable starts as "bird2c" for example, and each time the button is pushed, it will change to "bird3b" then "bird4a" etc. I just want to keep it from repeating and return nothing when the assets are depleted. Thanks!

Comment: Use a Set to store each generated word. When a new word has been generated then check if the word is already in the set and generate a new one until you have a new unique word and then use that word. Set is very good for this since it only contains unique instances.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Ok, will try. Again, really new to this. Would that mean I can just keep the code as is but preface the parameters used to create the string with a "set" notation? Then initiate some code to check if each new word is already in the set? (which I have an idea how to do but a little shaky on the details...)